# Alfresco maven sdk error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, workflow, alfresco

I am new to alfresco, activity and maven.I want to design activiti workflow using Eclipse Mars 4.5.0. But i have to set alfresco maven sdk first. There is Alfresco Maven sdk error is given below. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

pom.ml file is given below.

POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>workflowProcess</groupId>
    <artifactId>worflowProcessAr</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>worflowProcessAr AMP project</name>
    <packaging>amp</packaging>
    <description>Manages the lifecycle of the worflowProcessAr AMP (Alfresco Module Package)</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- 
       | SDK properties have sensible defaults in the SDK parent,
       | but you can override the properties below to use another version. 
       | For more available properties see the alfresco-sdk-parent POM. 
       -->
    <properties>
        <!-- Defines the alfresco edition to compile against. Allowed values are [org.alfresco|org.alfresco.enterprise]--> 
        <alfresco.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.groupId>
        <!-- Defines the alfresco version to compile against -->
        <alfresco.version>4.2.e</alfresco.version>
        <app.log.root.level>WARN</app.log.root.level>
        <alfresco.data.location>alf_data_dev</alfresco.data.location>
        <!-- Defines the target WAR artifactId to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch
        .    | Allowed values: alfresco | share. Defaults to a repository AMP, but could point to your foundation WAR -->
        <alfresco.client.war>alfresco</alfresco.client.war>
        <!-- Defines the target WAR groupId to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch
        .    | Could be org.alfresco | org.alfresco.enterprise or your corporate groupId -->
        <alfresco.client.war.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.client.war.groupId>
        <!-- Defines the target WAR version to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch -->
        <alfresco.client.war.version>4.2.e</alfresco.client.war.version>
        <!-- This controls which properties will be picked in src/test/properties for embedded run -->
        <env>local</env>
    </properties>

    <!-- Here we realize the connection with the Alfresco selected platform 
        (e.g.version and edition) -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- This will import the dependencyManagement for all artifacts in the selected Alfresco version/edition
                (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) 
                NOTE: You still need to define dependencies in your POM, but you can omit version as it's enforced by this dependencyManagement. NOTE: It defaults 
                to the latest version this SDK pom has been tested with, but alfresco version can/should be overridden in your project's pom -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>alfresco-platform-distribution</artifactId>
                <version>${alfresco.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- Following dependencies are needed for compiling Java code in src/main/java; 
         <scope>provided</scope> is inherited for each of the following; 
         for more info, please refer to alfresco-platform-distribution POM -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- This repository is only needed to retrieve Alfresco parent POM. 
        NOTE: This can be removed when/if Alfresco will be on Maven Central 

        NOTE: The repository to be used for Alfresco Enterprise artifacts is
        https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/private/. Please check
        with Alfresco Support to get credentials to add to your ~/.m2/settings.xml
        if you are a Enterprise customer or Partner  
        -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>alfresco-public</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>alfresco-public-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maven will resolve the dependency by downloading the parent pom when you build. Do that by completing these steps:

1. Right-click on the pom.xml file and select **Run As/Maven build...**
2. In Goals, type **install**. This tells Maven to download any dependencies it doesn't already have.
3. Click **Apply**, then **Run**.

This should result in a successful build and the resolution of that error.

Answer (score 0):

you can go ahead with "Finish", Eclips automatically resolve it by downloading.